# Block a specific port in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my_server.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

The application is run on port 8080. How can I block this port? I mean when some user opens http://my_server.com:8080 then server sends no response.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you configure a firewall to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better do at network level. For unix:

`iptables -A INPUT ! -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP`

See https://serverfault.com/a/248864